# Do the poles or the roots, or both, of the Laplace transform point to the resonant frequencies of a system?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

Resonance is explained [here](https://youtu.be/wmyBjNP3Mr0) as the matching of the frequency of the system with the drive in the RHS of the equation, so that the solution of the ODE grows to infinity:

$$u'' + 9u = 2 \sin 3t$$

with $$u=-\frac 1 3 t\cos 3t + C_1 \sin 3t + C_2 \cos 3t$$

[image]

The question is

> Shouldn't this resonant frequencies be [identified by the poles of the Laplace transform](https://youtu.be/5jYr0QktWxE?t=465)?

If I get the LT of $u$ (ignoring the null space) I get

$$\mathcal L\Big [-\frac 1 3 t \cos 3t \Big](s)= -\frac{s^2 - 9}{3(s^2+9)^2}$$

with roots $s=3$ and $s=-3,$ which seem to point to the resonant frequency, but no poles!

I thought that [the roots of the LT carried information on the amplitude of the solution equation](https://youtu.be/5jYr0QktWxE?t=660).

---

I see after the answer that I was taking the LT of the actual answer... So perhaps I should be reading the tea leaves on the LT of the initial equation, which according to Wolfram Alpha is:

$$ \frac{6+ 9 u'(0) + 9s u(0) + s^2 u'(0) + s^3 u(0)}{(s^2 +9)^2}$$

Comment: The amplitude is obviously *multiplied* by the modulus of the transfer function, hence only the poles amplify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Analyzing the process

$$
u'' + 9 u = v
$$

and assuming null initial conditions, the LT gives

$$
U(s)=\frac{1}{s^2+9}V(s)
$$

The resonance is associated to the transfer function modulus behavior with input frequencies or

$$
|U(\omega)| = \left|\frac{1}{9-\omega^2}\right||V(\omega)|
$$

where $\omega$ represents the angular frequency at the input $v(t)$. If in $v(t)$ appears a carrier with frequency $\omega = 3$  then the output amplitude at $U(3)$ goes to infinite.

Note that if instead we have

$$
u'' + 9 u' = v
$$

then in this case

$$
U(s)=\frac{1}{s(s+9)}V(s)
$$

and

$$
|U(\omega)| = \left|\frac{1}{9\omega\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{\omega}{9}\right)^2}}\right||V(\omega)|
$$

In this case if $v(t)$ has a carrier with frequency $\omega = 3$ the output will be limited without resonance.

NOTE

Given $G(s) = \frac{1}{s(s+9)}$ we obtain the module $|G(j\omega)|$ as follows:

Making $s = j\omega$

$$
G(j\omega) = \frac{1}{j\omega(j\omega+9)}
$$

and

$$
|G(j\omega)|=\sqrt{G(j\omega)G(-j\omega)} = \frac{1}{9\omega\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{\omega}{9}\right)^2}}
$$

Comment: Thank you. So much of your answer is over my head... Is the statement that $\omega = 3$ is a resonant frequency even true in the OP? What about the statement that the zeros of the LF as in the OP (which I got from Wolfram Alpha) gives this resonance frequency? Is it just a fluke?

Comment: To me the LT gives $$U(s) = \frac{6}{(s^2+9)^2}+\frac{sC_1}{s^2+9}+\frac{C_2}{s^2+9}$$. Here $C_1, C_2$ represent the initial/ boundary conditions.

Comment: In this reference there is a brief and precise definition of resonance regarding linear systems. https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Resonance

Comment: I have caught up with the background info re: [transfer functions and their LT](https://x-engineer.org/graduate-engineering/signals-systems/control-systems/find-transfer-function-system/), but I am now struggling with the "transfer function modulus behavior with input frequencies..." and I don't find the material you linked to all that easy. I'll keep on chipping away at the problem to try and fully understand your answer, but if there is anything you can add to explain the modulus formula, please let me know.

Comment: How do you arrive at the very last equation?

Comment: Please. See note attached.

Comment: Why isn't $s = r + j \omega,$ with $r$ being a real number?

Comment: $G(j\omega)$ is known as the harmonic response which is the linear system response to $e^{j\omega t}$ This equivalence can be observed and understood well, as established by the known Parseval-Bessel theorem.

Comment: I guess [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/275381) is it...

Comment: Don't forget that the transfer function is defined also for unstable systems....

Comment: I see this comment by the author of [this presentation](https://youtu.be/KDN8W_HaeAY?t=94) after defining $s=j\omega$: "Correction: I say "s = jw" always, but that is actually for calculating the frequency response, which is a very commonly used (and explained in a later video). "s" is technically any complex value which would have real and imaginary components, so "s = a + jb."